# Python - How to get the number of lines in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text, count

I would like to know if it s possible to know how many lines contains my file text without using a command as :

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    size = len(text)
```

My file is very huge so it s difficult to use this kind of approach...

Answer (score 32):

As a Pythonic approach you can count the number of lines using a generator expression within `sum` function as following:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
   count = sum(1 for _ in f)
```

Note that here the fileobject `f` is an iterator object that represents an iterator of file's lines.

Answer (score 12):

Slight modification to your approach

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    line_count = 0
    for line in f:
        line_count += 1

print line_count
```

**Notes:**

Here you would be going through line by line and will not load the complete file into the memory

Answer (score 6):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    size=len([0 for _ in f])
```

Answer (score 4):

The number of lines of a file is not stored in the metadata. So you actually have to run trough the whole file to figure it out. You can make it a bit more memory efficient though:

```
lines = 0
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = lines + 1
```