# Count line total in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a file with 4 lines. In Python, how can I check this?

Given this sudo text file

```
line
another line
yet another line
last line
```

How can I iterate through this file to find the line count? Does Python have a builtin for this?

SOLUTION:
With the builtin `len` function I was able to read the line total, thanks.

Comment: see if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607370/python-how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('filename') as f:
    print(len(f.readlines()))
```

This will print the number of lines in the file, because `readlines()` returns a list of lines in the file

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I'll accept once the timer allows me to.